# How to pass a a child module output to another child module as variable or input using terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure

I have a child module to create a few Azurerm RGs, here is a sample main.tf:

```
#Resource group module main.tf file
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "RG-SharedServices" {
    name     = "SharedServices-Dev-RG"
    location = var.location
    tags     = var.tags
} 
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "RG-Frontend" {
    name     = "Frontend-Dev-RG"
    location = var.location
    tags     = var.tags
} 
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "RG-Backend" {
    name     = "Backend-Dev-RG"
    location = var.location
    tags     = var.tags
}
```

I have to output those RGs names to be an input for another child module, an example of main.tf:

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "SA-DataIn" {
    name                     = var.name
    resource_group_name      = var.resource_group_name
    location                 = var.location
    account_tier             = var.account_tier
    account_replication_type = var.account_replication_type
    tags                     = var.tags
}
```

The structure:

```
TF_Repo\
main.tf
variable.tf
 \modules
   \Resource_Groups
     main.tf
     variable.tf
     output.tf
   \Storage_Accounts
     main.tf
     variable.tf
     output.tf
```

in TF_Repo\main.ft I have this code:

```
# Configure the Microsoft Azure Provider
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

module "Azure_Module_RG" {
  source = "./Modules/Resource_Groups"
}

module "Azure_Module_SA" {
  source = "./Modules/Storage_Accounts"
  depends_on = [ module.Azure_Module_RG ]  
}

module "Azure_Module_PstGrs" {
  source = "./Modules/DB_PostGreSQL"
  depends_on = [ module.Azure_Module_RG ]  
}


module "Azure_Module_WebApp" {
  source = "./Modules/Web_Apps"
  depends_on = [ module.Azure_Module_RG ]  
}
```

How can I pass The RGs names into modules without hard coding it?

I tried several Youtube videos and a few blogs, I found one that is working, but any slight change in any name did the code fail to apply.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to pass a a child module output to another child module as variable or input using terraform and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

This configuration require multiple steps to be followed as one resource was depends on another.

**`Step 1:`**

To pass the names of the Resource Groups to other modules, you need to create output values for each of them in your Resource Groups module (`/modules/Resource_Groups/output.tf`).

**`Step 2:`**

To use the outputs from the `Azure_Module_RG` module in your main Terraform configuration (`TF_Repo/main.tf`), you need to pass them as inputs to other modules. This is how you reference them in your main configuration.

To begin, make sure that every module that requires a Resource Group name has a corresponding variable declared in its `variable.tf` file. For example, your Storage Accounts module should have a `variable.tf` file that contains:

```
variable "resource_group_name" {
  description = "The name of the resource group"
  type        = string
}
```

My **`file structure`** for this requirement:

```
TF_Repo/
├── main.tf
├── variables.tf
└── modules/
    ├── Resource_Groups/
    │   ├── main.tf
    │     
    └── Storage_Accounts/
    |   ├── main.tf
    |   
    └── Virtual_Networks/
        ├── main.tf
```

**My terraform configuration:**

##### `TF_Repo/main.tf`

```
   provider "azurerm" {
      features {}
    }
    
    module "Azure_Module_RG1" {
      source   = "./modules/Resource_Groups"
      name     = var.resource_group_name1
      location = var.location
      tags     = var.common_tags
    }
    
    module "Azure_Module_RG2" {
      source   = "./modules/Resource_Groups"
      name     = var.resource_group_name2
      location = var.location
      tags     = var.common_tags
    }
    
    module "Azure_Module_SA" {
      source               = "./modules/Storage_Accounts"
      name                 = var.storage_account_name
      resource_group_name  = module.Azure_Module_RG1.resource_group_name
      location             = module.Azure_Module_RG1.resource_group_location
      account_tier         = var.storage_account_tier
      account_replication_type = var.storage_account_replication_type
      tags                 = var.common_tags
    }
    
    module "Azure_Module_VNet" {
      source               = "./modules/Virtual_Network"
      name                 = var.virtual_network_name
      resource_group_name  = module.Azure_Module_RG2.resource_group_name
      location             = module.Azure_Module_RG2.resource_group_location
      address_space        = var.virtual_network_address_space
      tags                 = var.common_tags
    }
```

#### `TF_Repo/variables.tf`

```
variable "resource_group_name1" {
  description = "The name of the first Azure Resource Group."
  type        = string
  default     = "demovksb-rg1"
}

variable "resource_group_name2" {
  description = "The name of the second Azure Resource Group."
  type        = string
  default     = "demovksb-rg2"
}

variable "virtual_network_name" {
  description = "The name of the Azure Virtual Network."
  type        = string
  default     = "demoVNet"
}

variable "virtual_network_address_space" {
  description = "The address space for the Azure Virtual Network."
  type        = list(string)
  default     = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}

variable "common_tags" {
  description = "Common tags to apply to all resources."
  type        = map(string)
  default     = {
    Terraform   = "true"
    Environment = "Development"
  }
}

variable "location" {
  description = "The Azure region where to deploy the resources."
  type        = string
  default     = "East US"
}

variable "storage_account_name" {
  description = "The name of the Azure Storage Account. Must be unique across Azure."
  type        = string
  default = "demsbvktest"
}

variable "storage_account_tier" {
  description = "Defines the Tier to use for this storage account."
  type        = string
  default     = "Standard"
}

variable "storage_account_replication_type" {
  description = "Defines the type of replication to use for this storage account."
  type        = string
  default     = "LRS"
}
```

##### `modules/Resource_Groups/main.tf`

```
variable "name" {
  description = "The name of the resource group."
  type        = string
  default = "demovksb-rg"
}

variable "location" {
  description = "The location of the resource group."
  type        = string
  default = "east us"
}

variable "tags" {
  description = "A map of tags to assign to the resource."
  type        = map(string)
  default     = {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = var.name
  location = var.location
  tags     = var.tags
}


output "resource_group_name" {
  value = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

output "resource_group_location" {
  value = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
}
```

##### `modules/Storage_Accounts/main.tf`

```
variable "name" {
  description = "The name of the storage account."
  type        = string
 
}

variable "resource_group_name" {
  description = "The name of the resource group the storage account is in."
  type        = string
}

variable "location" {
  description = "The location of the storage account."
  type        = string
}

variable "account_tier" {
  description = "Defines the Tier to use for this storage account."
  type        = string
}

variable "account_replication_type" {
  description = "Defines the type of replication to use for this storage account."
  type        = string
}

variable "tags" {
  description = "A map of tags to assign to the resource."
  type        = map(string)
  default     = {}
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "sa" {
  name                     = var.name
  resource_group_name      = var.resource_group_name
  location                 = var.location
  account_tier             = var.account_tier
  account_replication_type = var.account_replication_type
  tags                     = var.tags
}
```

**modules/Virtual_Networks/main.tf:**

```
variable "name" {
  description = "The name of the virtual network."
  type        = string
}

variable "resource_group_name" {
  description = "The name of the resource group the virtual network is in."
  type        = string
}

variable "location" {
  description = "The location of the virtual network."
  type        = string
}

variable "address_space" {
  description = "The address space for the virtual network."
  type        = list(string)
}

variable "tags" {
  description = "A map of tags to assign to the resource."
  type        = map(string)
  default     = {}
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = var.name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  location            = var.location
  address_space       = var.address_space
  tags                = var.tags
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This doesn't apply to my scenario, since I need to create more than 1 resource group.
This end with error in the root module main.tf at line: name     = var.resource_group_name

Comment: I provided the solution as per your requirement of multiple resource modules with one RG each here I provided multiple RG modules in the main.tf because The use of a single module instance for each resource group instead of creating separate modules for each resource group is based on the principle of DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) in software development, including infrastructure as code practices like Terraform. This principle encourages the reduction of duplication in code, which in turn makes the codebase easier to maintain, more scalable, and less prone to errors.